# JHipster generated endpoints adds header messages

Tags: design-patterns, spring, spring-mvc

I'm adding new functionality to an existing application it was done using JHipster.
I've notice that some endpoints follow this pattern:

```
return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(updatedUser,
        HeaderUtil.createAlert("userManagement.updated", userDTO.getLogin()));
```

The `wrapOrNotFound` method:

```
public static <X> ResponseEntity<X> wrapOrNotFound(Optional<X> maybeResponse, HttpHeaders header) {
    return maybeResponse.map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().headers(header).body(response))
        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

The `createAlert` method:

```
public static HttpHeaders createAlert(String message, String param) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("X-" + APPLICATION_NAME + "-alert", message);
    headers.add("X-" + APPLICATION_NAME + "-params", param);
    return headers;
}
```

Two things that I notice going on there:

1. The `wrapOrNotFound` is used to avoid custom exceptions with reponse status? , is this a common pattern?, does anyone know any good reading for this?
2. The added headers seems to be only information for the front-end, is this done for some specific purpose? Is a front-end framework requirement/good practice? Is it for logging purposes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding `ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(...)`**

The main use-case for JHipster is the development of CRUD applications. The tools it provides help kickstart the development of applications that manage potentially a lot of different types of entities. For each of these entities, the CRUD operations are very similar (though there may be some differences regarding validation, some entities reference other entities...). As a consequence there are common patterns for which it makes a lot of sense to have utility methods such as this one.

For this method in particular, it helps every time you allow the user to manipulate a specific entity. The simplest case would be getting a specific entity. From the API standpoint, for that you need to send a `GET` request to `/api/myEntity/entityId`. That path identifies a specific entity. Either that entity exists, and the expected HTTP response uses status code `200 OK`, or it does not and the expected response uses `404 NOT FOUND`. This behaviour is specific to the REST API exposed by the application.

Within the Java code, in order to know which answer to provide, you need to determine whether the entity exists, and if it does have it at hand to build the response body. The entity is likely stored in a database, and the simplest way to have all the information the API layer needs is to try to get the entity from it. Now you have several possibilities for this `getEntity(...)` operation :

1. It returns the entity if it exists, or `null` otherwise
2. It returns the entity if it exists, or it throws an exception otherwise
3. It returns an `Optional`, that models that it is not guaranteed that an entity can be returned by the operation

Of the three possibilities, the third one is preferable. Possibility 1 is error-prone, as one may forget to check whether the value is `null`, and it may result in buggy behaviour. Possibility 2 would be error-prone is the exception thrown is unchecked, and is definitely not ideal even with a checked exceptions. As the name implies, exceptions are for exceptional cases, but trying to get an entity that may not exist is actually an expected use-case as you have no control over the values provided by the potential API clients. Which leaves us with possibility 3, where `Optional` documents that there may be no value, and forces the code to handle that case in what is here a pretty elegant manner.

Now it looks like you are working on code that does not just read an entity, but actually updates it. You do not show the rest of the code, but I expect that `updatedUser` is an empty `Optional` if there was no user to update. In that case the behaviour of the REST API is expected to be the same as with my detailed explanation above.

With contexts similar as the one described here, having utility methods like `wrapOrNotFound(...)` is a pretty common pattern. This is a simple application of the DRY concept (Don't Repeat Yourself), that is well-applied here.

**Regarding the headers**

What you observe here is a rather JHipster-specific behaviour. That is not to say that there aren't other, unrelated code-bases that use a similar strategy ; but while I completely agree with the design choice described in the first half of my answer, I am on the fence regarding this one.

JHipster can be used to generate both Spring Boot back-end server and its associated Angular or React front-end client. The client, following data manipulation operations submitted to the server, shows the end-user Bootstrap "alerts" that tell them that the operation was successful (or not).

One could have the specific Javascript code that built the request read the response and trigger the showing of the alert component depending on the response status. But this is not the design choice that has been followed (at least in the version of JHipster I have used, that seems to have a similar behaviour as yours). Instead, it is the job of the back-end to provide the information the front-end needs to have to show the correct alert message as part of the response headers.

What that allows is for the client code for a specific operation not to bother with managing the alert. Instead an independent, generic interceptor object is used with the HTTP client that reads the headers of all the HTTP responses sent back by the server, and if it finds those set by the `HeaderUtil.createAlert(...)` method it triggers the showing of the alert component (via an intermediate service in the case of an Angular front-end -- I have not yet had to work with React clients generated with JHipster).

From my point of view this is not ideal design. I expect the front-end to be fully in charge of what it shows and when, and the back-end to be agnostic regarding front-end behaviour. As with everything in our field however, that it is not ideal does not mean that it does not work. As you can probably see in the application you are working on, it does work. But in a way that is surprising to some.